# splitting a string into parts using regex in R

Tags: regex, r, string

I need to split a string into three parts (itemName, delimiter, itemNum).  As a first attempt at learning regex/string-functions in R, I used "regex-magic" to generate the pattern

```
grepl("\\A[[:<:]][A-Za-z]+[._~-]*(?:[0-9]+)+[[:>:]]\\z", "bob.~-1234", perl=TRUE);
```

I think I understand, the three patterns: `[A-Za-z]+`, `[._~-]*` and `[0-9]+` mean. I am clueless about `\\A[[:<:]]` and `+[[:>:]]\\z`. I also do not understand how the optional delimiter is specified.

Also, what function do I need to return a vector with three parts: `"bob"`, `".~-"`, `"1234"`?

Comment: Is it possible to validate all three parts, before `strsplit()`? For example, `"bob1___1234", "bob_a123" & "1bob~.1234"` should be rejected. Should that be done in a prior step?

Comment: @user151410 If you need to reject those, then perhaps create a logical index `grepl('[^0-9]+\\.~-[0-9]+', str1)` and use `ifelse` to get those that are TRUE.  It is better to post a question with most of these cases rather than updating it in the middle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`\A` is an anchor which asserts that the current position in the string is the beginning of the string. The `\z` anchor asserts that the current position in the string is the **very** end of the string. POSIX [**word boundaries**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html) are defined as `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`. The first one is a start-of-word boundary, and the second one is an end-of-word boundary. You can leave them out here.

You can use `strapply` from the [**gsubfn**](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/gsubfn/index.html) package to match the entire pattern.

```
strapply('bob.~-1234', '\\A([a-zA-Z]+)([._~-]*)(\\d+)\\z', c, perl=T)[[1]]
# [1] "bob"  ".~-"  "1234"
```

Comment: great. I 'get' all three pieces. Are word boundaries optional in this case? Thanks.

Comment: Since you're using `\A` and `\z` they're not needed because you're matching word characters at the beginning of the string and digits at the end of the string.

Answer (score 2):

The POSIX standard defines `[[:<:]]` as a start-of-word boundary, and `[[:>:]]` as an end-of-word boundary.

You could try the below `strsplit` function to get your desired output.

```
> strsplit("bob.~-1234", "(?<=[._~-])(?=[0-9])|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=[._~-])",perl=T)
[[1]]
[1] "bob"  ".~-"  "1234"
```

OR

```
> strsplit("bob.~-1234", "(?<=\\w)(?=\\W)|(?<=\\W)(?=\\w)",perl=T)
[[1]]
[1] "bob"  ".~-"  "1234"
```